# Dynamic SQL - EXEC(@SQL) versus EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

What are the real world pros and cons of executing a dynamic SQL command in a stored procedure in SQL Server using

```
EXEC (@SQL)
```

versus

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`sp_executesql` is more likely to promote query plan reuse. When using `sp_executesql`, parameters are explicitly identified in the calling signature. This excellent article descibes this [process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc966425.aspx).

The oft cited reference for many aspects of dynamic sql is Erland Sommarskog's must read: "[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)".

Comment: Please can you add reason why sp_executesql allows query plan re-use where as exec does not?

Answer (score 24):

The big thing about SP_EXECUTESQL is that it allows you to create parameterized queries which is very good if you care about SQL injection.

Comment: I don't think you can parameteize a dynamic sql without it??

Comment: Absolutely one of the biggest reasons to use sp_executesql if building the query dynamically to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft's [Using sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) article recommends using `sp_executesql` instead of `execute` statement.

> Because this stored procedure supports **parameter substitution**,
>   sp_executesql is more versatile than EXECUTE; and because
>   sp_executesql generates execution plans that are more likely to be
>   reused by SQL Server, sp_executesql is **more efficient** than EXECUTE.

So, the take away: **Do not use `execute` statement**. Use `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Your takeaway does not stand always. There are occasions when there is no efficiency bonus by using sp_executesql, but you can protect your code from sql injection attack. Sometimes you just can't use sp_executesql the way you can use exec, so... someone said - there is no silver bullet. I agree.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft should have put it as "more *likely* to be efficient". And being in the industry for some years, I have seen cases where `sp_executesql` cannot be used to replace `execute`. Perhaps I should put the point I am trying to stress as: Use `sp_executesql` instead of `execute` *whenever possible*.

Comment: Please can you add reason why sp_executesql allows query plan re-use where as exec does not?

Answer (score 2):

I would always use sp_executesql these days, all it really is is a wrapper for EXEC which handles parameters & variables.

However do not forget about OPTION RECOMPILE when tuning queries on very large databases, especially where you have data spanned over more than one database and are using a CONSTRAINT to limit index scans.

Unless you use OPTION RECOMPILE, SQL server will attempt to create a "one size fits all" execution plan for your query, and will run a full index scan each time it is run.

This is much less efficient than a seek, and means it is potentially scanning entire indexes which are constrained to ranges which you are not even querying :@

Answer (score -2):

1. Declare the variable
2. Set it by your command and add dynamic parts like use parameter values of sp(here @IsMonday and @IsTuesday are sp params)
3. execute the command

   ```
   declare  @sql varchar (100)
   set @sql ='select * from #td1'

   if (@IsMonday+@IsTuesday !='')
   begin
   set @sql= @sql+' where PickupDay in ('''+@IsMonday+''','''+@IsTuesday+''' )'
   end
   exec( @sql)
   ```

Comment: This is open to SQL injection, if you put e.g. "a';DROP DATABASE DATABASE_NAME; GO;';" in the @IsMonday variable

Comment: is it prone to sql injuction if @IsMonday is int ?

Comment: @VikasRana @IsMonday cannot be `int` in dynamic SQL. Note that @sql is declared as `varchar` or `nvarchar`