# How to secure dynamic SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-injection, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure that takes in the name of a table as a parameter and uses dynamic sql to perform the select. I tried to pass @TableName as a parameter and use sp_executesql but that threw an error. I decided to go with straight dynamic sql without using sp_executesql.

Is there anything else I should be doing to secure the @TableName parameter to avoid sql injection attacks?

Stored procedure below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_GetRecords  
    (   
    @TableName VARCHAR(128) = NULL
    )   
AS
BEGIN   

    /* Secure the @TableName Parameter */          
    SET @TableName = REPLACE(@TableName, ' ','')    
    SET @TableName = REPLACE(@TableName, ';','')    
    SET @TableName = REPLACE(@TableName, '''','')

    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)    

    /* Validation */    
    IF @TableName IS NULL
    BEGIN       
        RETURN -1
    END 

    SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName
    EXEC(@query)        
END
```

This failed when using sp_executesql instead:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM @TableName' 
EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@TableName VARCHAR(128)', @TableName
```

> ERROR: Must declare the table variable
>   "@TableName".

Comment: Whichever solution you choose, be aware that when you execute dynamic SQL within a stored procedure, that SQL runs by default with the permissions of the stored proc *caller*. Whereas normal SQL in a stored procedure runs by default with the permissions of the stored proc *owner*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here:

[How should I pass a table name into a stored proc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246760/how-should-i-pass-a-table-name-into-a-stored-proc/1246848#1246848)

Answer (score 2):

you of course can look at the sysobjects table and ensure that it exists

```
Select id from sysobjects where xType = 'U' and [name] = @TableName
```

Further (more complete example):

```
DECLARE @TableName nVarChar(255)
DECLARE @Query nVarChar(512)

SET @TableName = 'YourTable'
SET @Query = 'Select * from ' + @TableName

-- Check if @TableName is valid
IF NOT (Select id from sysobjects where xType = 'U' and [name] = @TableName) IS NULL
     exec(@Query)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the unsafe string still be included in the query to verify the tables existence?

Comment: @jms but here you can use bind parameters