# Passing table name in sql stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to pass the table name as input parameter to the stored procedure?

For example:

```
create procedure test
@tablename char(10)
as
begin
select * from @tablename
end
go
```

I know this does not work. So what is the best way if I want to pass the table name into the stored procedure?

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I pass a table name into a stored proc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246760/how-should-i-pass-a-table-name-into-a-stored-proc)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The safest way to do this is via a view.

Create a view which unions all the tables you may wish to access (and which must all have the same column structure), and prefix the rows with the table name.

```
CREATE VIEW MultiTable
AS
    SELECT 'table1' AS TableName, * FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'table2' AS TableName, * FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'table3' AS TableName, * FROM table3
```

Your stored procedure can now filter on the table name:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @TableName varchar(100)
AS
    SELECT * FROM MultiTable WHERE TableName = @TableName
```

This is safer than using dynamic SQL creation and execution.

Comment: It should be noted that, by using "*", the example is assuming that all three tables have the same number of columns.  I believe that you would get an error otherwise.  Even if this were the case, as a best practice you should probably enumerate them in each SELECT.

Comment: @Buggieboy maybe getting that error if the columns are changes in only one of the tables is worthwhile........

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use dynamic SQL, but you need to be aware of potential sql injection risks you open yourself up to as if @tablename contained something dodgy, you could end up in a world of pain.

e.g.

```
-- basic check to see if a table with this name exists
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @tablename)
    RETURN

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(100)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename)
EXECUTE(@sql)
```

You need to be very careful with this approach, make sure you don't open up a can of security worms.

My other concern is that you may be trying to make generic data access sprocs which is usually a bad idea. Obviously I don't know your use case.

Comment: [Yours is case number one!](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Common_cases)

Comment: Thanks very much. There is almost negligible chance of sql injection because there is no user entry for the table name. Its only used by the application internally - and I want to avoid creating multiple stored prcs with the same logic except different table names

Comment: @Bridge - yes, I agree fully. The cases where I've truly needed to use a dynamic table name, I personally have generated the SQL in the application code. But it's not often I've found a genuine use case

Comment: @user1414575 - I would strongly recommend reading Erland Sommerskog's article (@Bridge's link). It does sound like a time saving/generic data access approach you are looking for which in my experience, is bad

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50)
SET @Name='Company'

EXEC('SELECT * from ' + @Name )
```

use this way to get record from database.