# SqlCommand Parameters.AddWithValue return @ instead of variable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this command but it keeps showing:

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[@User]
```

Code:

```
void DropTable()
{
      using (Command = new SqlCommand(CommandString = "DROP TABLE [dbo].[@User]", ConnectionString));
      Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", "TestUser");

      MessageBox.Show(Command.CommandText.ToString());
}
```

I checked the documentation which seems to be writen in the right way, I have restarted VS and rebuild the solution but keep getting the same error.

Any possible thought ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Also i forgot to mention that 
Command.Parameters["@User"].Value ="TestUser"; 
has the same result

Comment: You cannot use parameters for object identifiers. That's only for values. And [you should avoid `AddWithValue()`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Originaly the code was 
using (SqlCommand DeleteRenterInfo = new SqlCommand(CommandString = @"DROP TABLE [dbo].[" + User + "] )", ConnectionString))

which was running fine , but its not really nice and has many flaws especialy for sql injection

Comment: Not that this is a terribly good idea, I think what you're trying to do is build a stored procedure that takes a table name and drops that table.  Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105121/how-to-take-table-name-as-an-input-parameter-to-the-stored-procedure

Comment: Are you getting the value for the _user_ variable from user input?

Comment: @Steve No ,the programm get the all the values from select query (fillby), then user have only to select the desired user by clicking on him and the programm pass the value. In the code above I create a test variable to see if variable is passed inside the command string.