# How to alter table from C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, database

I want to add one column to an existing table in C#, if it doesn't already exist.   I know I have to use an 'alter table' command.

But I am not able to fire that command in my C# code.
How can I do?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and Sql Server 2008.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/CreatingDBProgrammaticallyMCB11282005064852AM/CreatingDBProgrammaticallyMCB.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Alter Table and Add a column programmatically ASP.Net & SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719449/c-sharp-alter-table-and-add-a-column-programmatically-asp-net-sql-server)

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting, Removed irrelevant greetings and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this :

```sql
Use [DatabaseName]
Go
if Not exists( Select * from sys.columns As clm
                where clm.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[TableName]')
                And clm.name = N'[ColumnName]'
              )
Begin

    Alter Table TableName
    Add ColumnName DataTypeName

End
```

Comment: thnx user3540365, Rajesh and raj. I appreciate your help.