# dynamic table name to be passed in sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to execute a sql query by using dynamic table name.

I tried below codes but none of these works for me and throws syntax error.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM  @Table1 D WITH (NOLOCK)',
    N'@Table1 nvarchar(40)',@Table1=N'master.dbo.ABCD_data'
```

OR

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM  master.dbo.+@Variable1+_data D WITH (NOLOCK)',
    N'@Variable1 nvarchar(4),',@Variable1=N'ABCD'
```

Can anybody help me in creating this dynamic table name ?

I get this query from sql profiler. Actually i m executing it in c# code and got this in profiler.

My C# code is very simple, its kind of this:

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM master.dbo.+@Variable1+_data D WITH (NOLOCK)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Variable1", "ABCD");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: I tried this way already but it did not help me

Comment: Perhaps you could post the C# code that leads to this query

Comment: I have added that now. You can see the updated code above.

Comment: This question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1246848/109122

Comment: Thats different than my question...

Comment: @GauravGogna No it isn't.  What's stated there will work here as well, and will also solve the SQL Injection vulnerability you're about to introduce.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: This isn't the best of questions, but the supposed duplicate doesn't even mention C#. I don't think you should mark questions as duplicate because of their poor quality. They have to be exact duplicates.

Comment: @Andomar, No they don't have to be *exact* to be closed as duplicates, but I agree that should be pretty similar.  However, I wasn't claiming it was a duplicate either.  I was stating that this question is in fact answered by the indicated link.  As for poor quality, I'll probably just downvote it.

Answer (score -1):

You can't pass table or column names as parameters.

The usual way around that is called "dynamic SQL":

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = 'select * from ' + quotename(@tablename);
exec (@sql);
```

Or to pass both table names and parameter values:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = 'select * from ' + quotename(@tablename) + ' where col1 = @par1';
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@par1 nvarchar(4)', @par1='val1';
```

A naive way to run this from C# (vulnerable to SQL injection):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"
    declare @sql nvarchar(max);
    set @sql = 'select * from " + "ABCD" + @"_data d with (nolock)';
    exec (@sql);
    ";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    adapter.Fill(dt);
```

To run this from C# while still using the `quotename` function:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"
    declare @sql nvarchar(max);
    set @sql = 'select * from ' + quotename(@tablename) + '_data d with (nolock)';
    exec (@sql);
    ";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", "ABCD");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Just be very careful you dfon't introduce SQL Injection vulnerabilities by being careful how `@tablename` gets its value.

Comment: You have a gold badge in [sql-server], did you believe this question had never been asked before?

Comment: @Tanner: Each variant is slightly different. This question includes `sp_executesql` with parameters, which the supposed "exact duplicate" does not. The supposed duplicate top answer refers to [Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) which is a resource for the most advanced of SQL Server users, a clear mismatch for this type of question.

Comment: hy guys thanks for trying but my case is different. i can't create the @sql variable and then execute it using exec(@sql) as Andomar did.

Actually I ran this query in c# code and got this query generated dynamically from sql profiler.

Comment: @Andomar No luck bro. I tried your way but not working.