# How should I pass a table name,column name and value into a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

Based on this post:
    [How should I pass a table name into a stored proc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246760/how-should-i-pass-a-table-name-into-a-stored-proc)

i wrote a procedure to accept a table name, column name and value of the column to check if the passed value exists in the passed table and column.

```
CREATE PROC spCountAnyTableRows
( 
@PassedTableName as NVarchar(255),
@PassedColumnName as NVarchar(255),
@PassedValue as NVarchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ActualTableName AS NVarchar(255)
DECLARE @ActualColumnName AS NVarchar(255)

SELECT @ActualTableName = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @PassedTableName

SELECT @ActualColumnName = QUOTENAME( COLUMN_NAME )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @PassedColumnName

DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @ActualTableName + ' WHERE ' + @ActualColumnName +' = ' + @PassedValue
PRINT @sql
EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

but the print statement return:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [AppRoles] WHERE [Name] = Admin
```

instead of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [AppRoles] WHERE [Name] = 'Admin'
```

how can i edit this line below to return the normal select statement.

```
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @ActualTableName + ' WHERE ' + @ActualColumnName +' = ' + @PassedValue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @ActualTableName + ' WHERE ' + @ActualColumnName +' = ''' + @PassedValue + ''''
```