# Creating reusable SQL commands in c# programing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have following query that works.

```
string sqlCommandText = "SELECT * FROM Admin_T where AdminID =
'" +  textBox.Text + "'";
```

It is a fix command and I cannot use it with user given Table names and Column names at run time.

What I am actually trying to make is command like

```
string sqlCommandText = "SELECT * FROM Admin_T where 
'" + UserGivenColumnName + "' = '" + conditionTB.Text + "'";
```

"UserGivenColumnName" can be any column that is part of that specific table.

Trying to create flexibility so that same command can be used under different circumstances.

Comment: What stops you from having a string reference named `UserGivenColumnName` and assign it whatever value you want ?

Comment: Is this just the simplified version of what you are really trying to do? Because I don't see a problem here in formatting a `string` using two variables.... side-note: watch out for sql injection when you create sql commands including user input!

Comment: Exception are handled Properly. No Exception Error.

Comment: Make the field names a select control on your form.  Then the user can only select valid fields and you only have to process another form field.

Comment: @BilalMirza You should avoid creating queries dynamically, [read more about SQLInjection](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/)

Comment: Bad approach with query as concatenated string - target for SQL Injection. Even if `UserGivenColumnName` is getting from user input, then you cannot use parameters for column name.Consider [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx).

Comment: Not fetching any thing at all from Database.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1246848/109122.

Answer (score 0):

`SqlCommand` and none of related classes used by ADO.NET does not support such a functionality as far as I know.

Of course your should *never* build your sql queries with string concatenation. You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

But prepared statements *only* for values, not column names or table names. If you *really* wanna put your input string to your column name, create a whitelist and use it as a validation before you put it in your query.

http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture/

Answer (score 0):

I think an Object-Relational Mapper (ORM) is perhaps the droid you are looking for. [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx) might be a good place to start.

Please also do take the time to understand what SQL injection is, as the other users have also prompted you to.

Answer (score 0):

It is not returning anything as it is just comparing two strings
With the 'UserGivenColumnName' it is a string comparison
And those two strings are not equal

You can do it (column) by just not including the '
But it is still a bad idea
[SQLinjection](http://bobby-tables.com/) is a very real and very bad thing

```
string sqlCommandText =   
"SELECT * FROM Admin_T where " + UserGivenColumnName + " = '" + conditionTB.Text + "'";
```

or

```
string sqlCommandText =   
"SELECT * FROM Admin_T where [" + UserGivenColumnName + "] = '" + conditionTB.Text + "'";
```