# I need to create a sql server database table using visual studio(c# language) . But the name of the table has to be an input from the user

Tags: c#, winforms

```
con1.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("create table [dbo.][" + textBox2.Text + "](sno int primary key identity(1,1),[Week] [int]  not null ,Date nvarchar(30) not null,Time nvarchar(30) not null,Monday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Monday_2nd_half nvarchar(20),Tuesday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Tuesday_2nd_half nvarchar(20),Wednesday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Wednesday_2nd_half nvarchar(20),Thursday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Thursday_2nd_half nvarchar(20),Friday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Friday_2nd_half nvarchar(20),Saturday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Saturday_2nd_half nvarchar(20),Sunday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Sunday_2nd_half nvarchar(20))", con1);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con1.Close();
```

This query works if i give the table a hard coded name instead of the textbox.text value, a table is created.
But when i use this code it creates a table with the name 'dbo.'.
If i delete the "[dbo.]" from the query, it  gives an error saying 'object is missing'. can someone help me out?.

Comment: fyi this is asking for sql injection.

Comment: Aside from the horrible SQL injection vulnerability, the square brackets should be around the `dbo` not including the period e.g. `create table [dbo].[table] ...`

Comment: A stored procedure would be much better to do this, pass the table name as a parameter. and of course don't use this command text, as its very easy for SQL injection

Comment: @Yaman I don't think you can pass table names as a parameter.

Comment: @LarsTech something like this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246760/how-should-i-pass-a-table-name-into-a-stored-proc

Comment: Guys... Thank you so much for your replies..  I know its a bad practice to code like this..its actually my very first project.. i am a beginner in college and its a test..i only have to get this code it work ...ill eventually get used to a safer method of coding like you guys mentioned. anyways ill try using a stored procedure like you mentioned @Yaman. Thank you DavidG, corrected that...still no effect..

Comment: You can do this (more) safely with a stored procedure and dynamic sql.  I have posted an example.

Comment: @Yaman I do like the answer at that link ... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a better way to do this.  First create the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.MakeUserTable(@Tablename as SYSNAME) As

    DECLARE @CleanName As SYSNAME;
    SET @CleanName = QUOTENAME(@Tablename, '[');

    DECLARE @sql As NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @sql = 'create table [dbo].' + @CleanName + '(sno int primary key identity(1,1),[Week] [int]  not null ,Date nvarchar(30) not null,Time nvarchar(30) not null,Monday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Monday_2nd_half nvarchar(20),Tuesday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Tuesday_2nd_half nvarchar(20),Wednesday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Wednesday_2nd_half nvarchar(20),Thursday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Thursday_2nd_half nvarchar(20),Friday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Friday_2nd_half nvarchar(20),Saturday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Saturday_2nd_half nvarchar(20),Sunday_1st_half nvarchar(20),Sunday_2nd_half nvarchar(20));'

    PRINT 'Executing "'+@sql+'"';
    EXEC(@sql);
```

Now change your client code to execute this instead, passing in the tablename as a parameter.

I cannot 100% guarantee that this is immune to SQL Injection attacks, but if you have to accept a tablename from a user, this is about as safe as you can get.

Comment: Oops, found a bug.  Corrected now.

Comment: Thank you so much @RBarry Young..I'll try this and get back to you :)

Comment: While using `QUOTENAME` fixes the SQL injection problem, it doesn't fix what is a very bad design. Much better to use a single table, perhaps with an extra column to identify which user those rows belong to.

Comment: @DavidG It depends on why and what is really going on here, but yeah, probably.

Comment: Also @RBarryYoung why not close as a dupe as this answer is effectively the same as your other one linked above? (and that answer is much more comprehensive!)

Comment: @DavidG It's not actually the same.  That question was asking about passing an *existing* tablename, for which there is a much better solution.  (and probably a much better justification)

Comment: Conceptually it's the same though, "passing a table name into a query".

Comment: @DavidG but again, the answer I posted there cannot be used here.  The use of `QUOTENAME` in that answer is peripheral, but in this answer it is essential.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that is a destination answer could be made into a great canonical, then it's a valid dupe target. That answer could be that with a little work.

Comment: While I immodestly agree that that is a great answer (one of my best ever), IMHO what makes it great is the same thing that makes it inapplicable to this question: the use of the existing table names.