# Perform Merge Statement dynamically using stored procedure when the source and target table names passed in parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some knowledge or guidance on T-SQL coding.

I want to build a stored procedure which will do a merge transaction by taking source and target tables from its parameters. I also want to use source and target column names dynamically inside the stored procedure.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need DynamicSQL, write your query and concatenate in the parameter values, and execute with `exec sp_executesql`

Comment: Hi Stu, do you have any article/blogs which can be used for me as reference guide.

Comment: I just searched on StackOverflow and [found this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212815/parameterize-table-name-in-dynamic-sql)

Comment: HI Stu, can you help me how to convert rows into columns in  sql.
For example if i run the query 

SELECT
 column_name
FROM
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
 TABLE_NAME = 'sampletable'

Now i want to put the values as column names in a dynamic select statement. can you suggest me how to do it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service; have a go, show us what you can do and if necessary ask for help about a *specific* problem you cannot resolve.

Comment: You can find a good start on this here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1246848/109122.  However, be forewarned, doing this for a MERGE is a lot more complicated than for a SELECT.  Also, pay close attention to the security warnings there.

Comment: This approach has a bad smell even if it works. I suggest you read about [coupling and cohesion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/software-engineering-coupling-and-cohesion/) first. And a module that will attempt to merge any two tables will require significant skill in writing tsql and handling errors.