# parameter as column name in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get values by keeping parameter in where clause like below :

```
DECLARE  @COLUMNNAME VARCHAR(50)
-- setting required column name 
SET @COLUMNNAME = (select name from sys.columns where OBJECT_ID = 
    (SELECT OBJECT_ID FROM SYS.objects WHERE name = 'BORVALIDATION') AND column_id = 2) 
--PRINT @COLUMNNAME (we do get the column name)
SELECT * FROM BORVALIDATION WHERE @COLUMNNAME = 'BBNAME'
```

Your knowledge and help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Like using dynamic SQL?

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you are asking here. Can you restate the question?

Comment: the code is taking column name of table in parameter(@columnname),
e.g. column name is Column2
im trying to write
SELECT * FROM BORVALIDATION WHERE @COLUMNNAME (i.e. Column2) = 'BBNAME'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pass column name as input parameter in SQL stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092869/can-i-pass-column-name-as-input-parameter-in-sql-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
Declare @SQL VARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM BORVALIDATION WHERE ' + @COLUMNNAME + '= ''BBNAME''';
EXEC(@SQL);
```