# Why would changing the parameter name in a parameterized query cause an SqlException to be thrown?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, prepared-statement

My Original query used @WF_ID as the parameter name and would execute without any problems. I am lazy though and WF_ was to much typing so I renamed the parameter to @ID but now when executed an SQLException is thrown. The exact message is "Invalid column name '_Page'"

Here are the two versions of the query and corresponding code. As you can see the only thing that has changed is the parameter name.

```
SQL_Connection.Open();
SQL_Command.Connection = SQL_Connection;
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@WF_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
param.Value = WF_ID;
SQL_Command.Parameters.Add(param);
SQL_Command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS MyCount from members WHERE ID = @WF_ID";
int numRows = Convert.ToInt32(SQL_Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
SQL_Command.Parameters.Clear();
```

Version 2.0 the broken version

```
 SQL_Connection.Open();
 SQL_Command.Connection = SQL_Connection;
 SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
 param.Value = WF_ID;
 SQL_Command.Parameters.Add(param);
 SQL_Command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS MyCount from members WHERE ID = @ID";
 int numRows = Convert.ToInt32(SQL_Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
 SQL_Command.Parameters.Clear();
```

My Initial thought was a parameter name cannot be the same as one of the column names...but I can't find anything that explicitly says that.

Looking at this StackOverflow topic it would seem that you couldn't pass a column name via parameters. [Can I pass column name as input parameter in SQL stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092869/can-i-pass-column-name-as-input-parameter-in-sql-stored-procedure)

Comment: To text your theory rename it to something other than the two names already used and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) AS MyCount from members WHERE ID = " + @WF_ID;
```

This is not a parameterized query at all. You just concatenated the value to your SQL string.

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) AS MyCount from members WHERE ID = @WF_ID";
```

This would make it use your parameter.

Comment: My bad. I had been playing around with the code trying different things to figure this out and forgot to change it back when making the post.