# STORED PROD FOR UPDATE SQL QUERY WHERE COLUMN NAME IS DYNAMIC

Tags: sql-server

Lets say I want to write a stored prod

[For SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092869/can-i-pass-column-name-as-input-parameter-in-sql-stored-procedure)

I found the above link for SELECT, but I want to do is for UPDATE:

```
SpUpdate @TableName varchar(50), @ColumnName varchar(50), @Value int, @Condition int

AS
BEGIN
 UPDATE @Tablename
 SET @ColumnName = @Value
 Where PrimaryColName = @Condition
END
```

I know above code wont run.  I know you can write a Dynamic code but I am not interested in Dynamic code.  Can anyone help with different approch.  Maybe using case statement or If statemens.

Comment: sql server or mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SpUpdate 
  @TableName  SYSNAME
, @ColumnName SYSNAME
, @Value      INT
, @Condition  INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql =  N' UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
          + N' SET ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N' = @Value '
          + N' WHERE PrimaryColName = @Condition '

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                     ,N'@Value INT, @Condition INT'
                     ,@Value
                     ,@Condition
END
```

Comment: you cannot do this without dynamic sql. by the way why you dont want to use dynamic sql ? any particular reason ?

Comment: party of company policy.  Thanks

Comment: is policy maker a SQL Server DBA ? if he is show him this code and his mind will be at peace, if he is not a DBA dont bother listening to him .

Comment: hehe.  I need to survive.

Comment: I reckon whoever has made this policy, have their doubts about sql injection, this piece of code I have written for you is clean and protected against sql injection attack. show it to your dba and it should be ok.

Comment: Can you explain the N' for me.  That is kind of new to me.  Once again, thanks a lot for all your help.