# Why are my variables do not change their values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm writting a big procedure in T-SQL with dynamic elements. To make it short for you I only post the important codelines.

```
declare....

BEGIN

while @start <= @rowcount
begin
  print @start
  print @rowcount

  set @sqlval = 'select @zwischen1 = @currentcolumn_val1
                 from z_skm
                 where id = @startid';

  set @ParmDefinitionval = N'@currentcolumn_val1 nvarchar(500),
                             @startid int,
                             @zwischen1 nvarchar(50) OUTPUT';

  exec sp_executesql
    @sqlval,
    @ParmDefinitionval,
    @currentcolumn_val1 = @currentcolumn_val,
    @startid = @start,
    @zwischen1 = @currentval OUTPUT;

  print @currentval


  set @sqlkey ='select @zwischen2 = @currentcolumn_key1
                from z_skm
                where id = @startid';

  set @ParmDefinitionkey = N'@Currentcolumn_key1 nvarchar(500),
                             @startid int,
                             @zwischen2 nvarchar(50) OUTPUT';

  exec sp_executesql
    @sqlkey,
    @ParmDefinitionkey,
    @Currentcolumn_key1 = @currentcolumn_key,
    @startid = @start,
    @zwischen2 = @currentkey OUTPUT;

  print @currentkey

  set @start = @start + 1
  print'loop-end'

end

END
GO
```

My problem is, that it always prints the same values. And the values are the ones which are passed at `@ParmDefinitionKey` and `@parmdefinitionval` into `@currentcolumn_key1` and `@Currentcolumn_val1`.

I hope you guys can help out.

Edit:

Now it works. Here is the change in the code :

```
set @sqlval = 'select @zwischen1 = '+@currentcolumn_val+' from z_skm where id = @startid';
SET @ParmDefinitionval = N'@startid int,@zwischen1 nvarchar(50) OUTPUT' ;
exec sp_executesql @sqlval,@ParmDefinitionval,@startid=@start,@zwischen1=@currentval OUTPUT;



set @sqlkey ='select @zwischen2 = '+@currentcolumn_key+' from z_skm where id = @startid';
set @ParmDefinitionkey=N'@startid int, @zwischen2 nvarchar(50) OUTPUT';
exec sp_executesql @sqlkey,@ParmDefinitionkey,@startid=@start,@zwischen2=@currentkey OUTPUT;
```

I dont know why, but it looks like that it is not possible to pass the dynamic_column  via argument into the execute, it needed to placed into the string before.. This made absolutely no sense for me.

Comment: If `@currentcolumn_val1` and `@currentcolumn_key1` are supposed to represent dynamic column names, then [you cannot do that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10092869/11683).

Comment: '@currentcolumn_val1' and '@currentcolumn_key1' represent the dynamic column values which stay the same for all loops. The '@startid' var changes. 
'@currentkey' and '@currentval' should print the single line value from the select statement

Comment: I don't understand your "dynamic column values." If `@currentcolumn_key1` contains name of the column, then you cannot do that and should use a workaround from the link. If `@currentcolumn_key1` does not contain the name of the column, then your whole query does not make sense and can be replaced with `set @var1 = @var2`.

Comment: Greg see my edit. Is this what you wanted to teach me?

Comment: steve, if you want to 'ping' another user in a comment, you can do it using the '@' symbol like this: @GSerg, see my edit.  Is this what you were trying to explain to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change your queries like this,

```
set @sqlval = 'select '+@zwischen1+' = '+@currentcolumn_val1+'
                 from z_skm
                 where id = '+@startid;
```

I think @zwischen1 is variable that hold the Column name

Comment: no @zwischen1 should hold the value of the sql statement

Comment: @steve did you try the query?

Comment: hey Dony, thx for your answer. Now it works. You can see my changes in the original question.

Comment: @steve If it correct please accept my answer, it help to remove the question from Unanswered queue.

Comment: I accepted your answer but wanted to let you know that not all dynamic values need to be placed into '@sqlval' before the execute. BUT it was necessery for the columnname.