# c# mysql DELETE FROM STRING WHERE.... I try use string as table name

Tags: c#, mysql

so I have string which is named as column name how should I write string as a column name into query? Here is my code :

```
string pas;
MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
cnn.Open();
string likvidavimas = "DELETE FROM '"+ pas +"' WHERE ID='"+ ID +"'";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(likvidavimas, cnn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: ok so you are passing the Delete from SQL Text.. where are you calling the `likvidavimas.ExecuteNonQuery` ? please show all relevant code also I would change that query to utilize Parameters it's called `Parameterized Query` or look up how to use the `string.Format` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the apostrophes from the tablename

```
MySqlCommand likvidavimas = "DELETE FROM "+ pas +" WHERE ID='"+ ID +"'";
```

But i would also use sql-parameters to prevent sql injection.

```
MySqlCommand likvidavimas = "DELETE FROM "+ pas +" WHERE ID=@ID";
likvidavimas.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't leave yourself open to security issues, this is really not a good idea in my opinion. I would personally avoid the use of dynamic sql and just write out a different query for each column you need to edit. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092869/can-i-pass-column-name-as-input-parameter-in-sql-stored-procedure) if you are dead set on this approach.

Like this...

```
string pas;
using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string likvidavimas = string.empty;
    if (pas == "Table1")
    {
        likvidavimas = "DELETE FROM [Table1] WHERE ID=@ID";
    }
    else if (pas == "Table2")
    {
        likvidavimas = "DELETE FROM [Table2] WHERE ID=@ID";
    }
    likvidavimas.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    cnn.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(likvidavimas, cnn))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Also, I always suggest using `using` to help clean up your resources at the end of execution. Not sure what `MySqlCommand` will be, but if it is `IDisposable` I'd say wrap it as well.

Comment: The OP is deleting rows from a table, not editing columns.  Though I agree it would be better to hard code the table names if possible.

Comment: I know, it's just a terrible idea to go this route. Someone could still fairly easily wipe out their db with this wide open query. Taking these kinds of risks scare me! :o    Not worth the "convenience".

Comment: It really depends on how the `pas` variable is set.  This might be inside of a private function and all calls to it pass a hard coded value for `pas`.

Comment: This is true, but based on the above code, I doubt it.

Comment: Actually based on the code `pas` is `null`, but I assume the OP has left something out.

Comment: Then ACTUALLY based on the code we can safely deduct that there is no private function and `pas` is `null`. :D

Comment: How can you delete from a column? If you want to delete  a value you do `UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName = NULL WHERE ID = @ID`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hehe... Oops! Through `SQL` magic of course! I updated it to `Table`s.