# passing column name as a parameter in IBM mobile first adapter

Tags: sql, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I want pass the column name as a parameter to the sql statement which I am using in the Mobile first adapter. I tried with the following :

```
var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from table1 where ?='employee'");
function validate(columnname) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
        parameters : [columnname]
    });

}
```

but it is returning an empty result set:

```
{
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "resultSet": [
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I am reading about SQL, it is not possible to simply pass the column name as a parameter.

However there are alternate ways to do so, for example see here: [Can I pass column name as input parameter in SQL stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092869/can-i-pass-column-name-as-input-parameter-in-sql-stored-procedure)

Basically you'll need to understand beforehand which column is required and based on that information construct your SQL query. So in your case you can implement a CASE and depending on the parameter ("column") value, you'll use a different query.

Comment: Using switch case is little complex in my case. there are 31 columns in my table and depending on the current date respective column name has to  be called