# Query is correct but it displays nothing no error or anything

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have this block of code. There is no error shown but when I try to execute it it displays nothing, to make sure I tried the query in sql and it displays data.Im using vb.net

```
Dim cmdSearch As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UserScanner WHERE @Condition = @Search", Connection)
    cmdSearch.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmdSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condition", searchcondition)
    cmdSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", txt_search.Text)
    cmdSearch.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSearch)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    With D
        .DataSource = dt
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
        .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Name"
        .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Address"
        .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Contact"
        .Columns(4).HeaderText = "Subscription Start"
        .Columns(5).HeaderText = "Subscription End"
    End With
```

Comment: You cannot use a parameter to define a column name.

Comment: What is the search condition? What are you searching? Can you put a breakpoint and let us know what you're iterating after, and what's the database & result suppoused to look like?

Comment: @steve is it not possible?

Comment: @A.Abramov any column possible. ID,Name,Subscription Start,Subscription End but Im trying at column ID first.

Comment: You should use a dynamic sql approach. More complex See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092869/can-i-pass-column-name-as-input-parameter-in-sql-stored-procedure

Comment: @KristaleGenessaOrdiz-Magallo Which one doesn't work for you? Put breakpoints and add the entire query.