# Using column name as parameter and using input parameter in WHERE/HAVING clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the number of an item based on a boolean field. The boolean field is a dynamic field passed as a parameter (as demonstrated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10092975/5849779)) during runtime.

EDIT: Finally solved it. Just changed the WHEN lines to: `WHEN 'SI_A'   THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SI_A=1 THEN 1 END)`. Thanks @FDavidov!

```
    SELECT
        OrganismName
        , MONTH(DateDiscovered) AS 'Month'
        , CASE @Column
            WHEN 'SI_A' THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SI_A=1 THEN 1 END)
            WHEN 'SI_B' THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SI_B=1 THEN 1 END)
            WHEN 'SI_C' THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SI_C=1 THEN 1 END)
            WHEN 'SI_D' THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SI_D=1 THEN 1 END)
        END AS 'Cases'
    FROM tblFindings
    INNER JOIN
        tblOrganism
    ON
        tblFindings.OrganismID = tblOrganism.OrganismID
    WHERE
        (SELECT 
            CASE @Column
            WHEN 'SI_A' THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SI_A=1 THEN 1 END)
            WHEN 'SI_B' THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SI_B=1 THEN 1 END)
            WHEN 'SI_C' THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SI_C=1 THEN 1 END)
            WHEN 'SI_D' THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SI_D=1 THEN 1 END)
        END AS 'Cases'
        FROM tblFindings
        INNER JOIN
            tblOrganism
        ON
            tblFindings.OrganismID = tblOrganism.OrganismID
        ) > 0
    GROUP BY
        OrganismName
        , MONTH(DateDiscovered)
    ORDER BY
        OrganismName
        , MONTH(DateDiscovered)
```

EDIT: Forgot to include the full table. I tried using UNPIVOT but I'm getting the error: 'OrganismID was specified multiple times in u'. This one does not pass the column name as a parameter however:

```
SELECT
    OrganismName
    , MONTH(DateDiscovered) AS 'Month'
    , u.Cases
    , u.Sites
FROM tblFindings
INNER JOIN tblOrganism ON tblFindings.OrganismID = tblOrganism.OrganismID
UNPIVOT (
    Cases FOR Sites in (SI_A, SI_B, SI_C, SI_D) 
    ) u
WHERE u.Cases > 0
```

[Table structure/sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XqRV.png)

Using this [code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1af8f7a6ed546dfcfa25619d8f5db430), I'm also getting rows that have a total of 0.
This is the result that I'm trying to achieve:

```
=========================
|OrganismName|Month|SI_A|
=========================
|nota        |2    |2   |
|something   |10   |1   |
|woo         |2    |1   |
=========================

=========================
|OrganismName|Month|SI_B|
=========================
|something   |4    |1   |
|something   |10   |1   |
=========================

=========================
|OrganismName|Month|SI_C|
=========================
|something   |10   |2   |
=========================

=========================
|OrganismName|Month|SI_D|
=========================
|something   |10   |1   |
=========================
```

Instead, I'm getting this (if I feed "SI_A" as parameter):

```
==========================
|OrganismName|Month|Cases|
==========================
|nota        |2    |2    |
|something   |4    |0    |
|something   |10   |1    |
|woo         |2    |1    |
|woo         |7    |0    |
==========================
```

I used a WHERE clause but got the result above. Then I tried a HAVING clause, but I got the same results. I'm not too familiar with SQL aside from doing simple queries, but how would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: `select ... from (<all of your current select statement with group by>) where cases > 0` - put that resuls (with 0s) into subquery or CTE and apply additional filters on the next level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is reflected in your presented results, but here is a hint to an obvious error (and from here you may be able to resolve your problem):

```
SELECT 
   OrganismName 
   MONTH(DateDiscovered) AS 'Month' 
 , CASE @Column 
      WHEN 'SI_A'   THEN SUM(CASE WHEN SI_A=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      WHEN 'SI_B'   THEN SUM(CASE WHEN SI_B=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      WHEN 'SI_C'   THEN SUM(CASE WHEN SI_C=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      WHEN 'SI_D'   THEN SUM(CASE WHEN SI_D=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      ELSE NULL 
 END AS 'Cases' 
FROM tblFindings 
....
```

You are checking if (for instance) `SI_A` is `1` to add `1` otherwise `0`. Now, what happens if `SI_A = 2`? You are also adding `0`.

Since I don't quite understand if you what t0 **SUM** all the values or **COUNT** how many cases you have a value > 0, I'm posting here both cases:

For SUM:

```
... WHEN 'SI_A' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN SI_A > 0 THEN SI_A ELSE 0 END) ...
```

or

```
... WHEN 'SI_A' THEN SUM(SI_A) ...
```

(the second is equivalent assuming that you are only getting `0` or a number > `0`).

For COUNT:

```
... WHEN 'SI_A' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN SI_A > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ...
```

Hope this is the solution you were looing for.

**UPDATE**

Here is a single and simple select you can start from:

```
SELECT 
   OrganismName 
   MONTH(DateDiscovered) AS 'Month' 
 , CASE @Column 
      WHEN 'SI_A'   THEN SUM(CASE WHEN SI_A > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      WHEN 'SI_B'   THEN SUM(CASE WHEN SI_B > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      WHEN 'SI_C'   THEN SUM(CASE WHEN SI_C > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      WHEN 'SI_D'   THEN SUM(CASE WHEN SI_D > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      ELSE NULL 
 END AS @Column 
FROM tblFindings
```

I guess this will do it.

Comment: Oh right, I was supposed to COUNT the items when they're TRUE. I tried that code and got rid of the 0's. I've since edited my code and tried using UNPIVOT but came across an error. Do you happen to know why I'm getting the column found multiple times in the UNPIVOT clause?

Comment: I suppose as an alternate approach. I'm checking if I got the correct values right now (got rid of the 0s) using the condition: `WHEN 'SI_A' THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SI_A=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the code is working properly. I changed the value of the column name parameter and I'm still getting the same set of values all over.

Comment: You mean you set a different value for `@Column` and get the results that match the previous value of this variable?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening with the code after I changed the previous WHEN conditions to `WHEN 'SI_A' THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SI_A=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Two steps: First, enter the LITERAL value of @Column into the query (two locations) as `'SI_A'` (and test the other values). If this works ok, Second step: edit your question and ADD your EXACT query (as an addition, not a replacement).

Comment: Okay, I think I got it now. `WHEN 'SIBlood' THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SI_A=1 THEN 1 END)` works just fine now. Thank you so much! If it weren't for you mentioning COUNT, I totally wouldn't have gotten anywhere :)