# "WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL" in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

`tracking_table` is a log table declared as follows:

```
create table tracking_table (my_command nvarchar(500), my_date datetime);
```

Please suppose you have the following block of SQL SERVER 2005 code, declared within a SQL Server 2005 job:

```
DECLARE @my_statement NVARCHAR(500)  
delete from tracking_table
   SET @my_statement = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON my_user.dbo.my_fact_table REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)'
insert into tracking_table values (@my_statement,getdate()) 
EXEC (@my_statement)  
 SET @my_statement = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON my_user.dbo.my_second_table REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)'
insert into tracking_table (@my_statement,getdate())    
EXEC (@my_statement)
```

At runtime, if the first statement (`ALTER INDEX ALL ON my_user.dbo.my_fact_table REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR=90)`) fails, the second statement which acts on my_second table WON'T be executed.

I would like to know how could I modify the SQL Server 2005 code, in order to skip any error, going forward (in Oracle I would say, `WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL`).

How could I achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: You could put each statement into its own job step, and then define what to do for each step if a failure occurs (stop execution, notify via e-mail, continue on, etc.)

Comment: I am obliged to use only one job step with all the code inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot advice to suppress errors, but if you really want to do it, I think you can try:

```
declare @my_statement nvarchar(500)  

begin try
    delete from tracking_table
end try
begin catch
    print null // or errormessage
end catch

begin try
    set @my_statement = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON my_user.dbo.my_fact_table REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)'

    insert into tracking_table values (@my_statement,getdate()) 
    exec (@my_statement)  
end try
begin catch
    print null // or errormessage
end catch

begin try
    set @my_statement = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON my_user.dbo.my_second_table REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)'

    insert into tracking_table (@my_statement,getdate())    
    exec (@my_statement)  
end try
begin catch
    print null // or errormessage
end catch
```

you can also create procedure

```
create procedure sp_executesql_Suppress_Errors
(
     @stmt nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin
    begin try
        exec sp_executesql
            @stmt = @stmt
    end try
    begin catch
        print null // or errormessage
    end catch
end
```

and then call it with your statements. I also advice you to use `exec sp_executesql` instead of `exec` (see [Dynamic SQL - EXEC(@SQL) versus EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548090/dynamic-sql-execsql-versus-exec-sp-executesqlsql))

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind cooperation. Answer accepted!

Comment: Thank you again for your sp_Suppress_Errors procedure!  Useful!!