# sp_executesql throws error but simple EXEC() works

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

I need to create a user defined type in dynamic way but

The `exec()` way:

```
-- This works
DECLARE @column NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Id INT'
EXEC ('CREATE TYPE dbo.MyDataType AS TABLE ('+ @column +')')
```

The `sp_executesql` way:

```
-- This does not work
DECLARE @column NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Id INT'
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'CREATE TYPE dbo.MyDataType AS TABLE ( @column )', @column;
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Id'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '@column'.

What am I missing ?

Comment: You can't specify column names with a parameter. You need to execute dynamic SQL for that. The same is true for table names, and any SQL object name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL even when taking the `sp_executesql` approach:

```
DECLARE @column NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Id INT'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'CREATE TYPE dbo.MyDataType AS TABLE ( ' + @column + ')'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

You can pass parameter definitions and values into `sp_executesql`, like this:

```
DECLARE @IntVariable int;  
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);  

/* Build the SQL string one time.*/  
SET @SQLString =  
     N'SELECT BusinessEntityID, NationalIDNumber, JobTitle, LoginID  
       FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee   
       WHERE BusinessEntityID = @BusinessEntityID';  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@BusinessEntityID tinyint';  

/* Execute the string with the first parameter value. */  
SET @IntVariable = 197;  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,  
                      @BusinessEntityID = @IntVariable;  

/* Execute the same string with the second parameter value. */  
SET @IntVariable = 109;  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,  
                      @BusinessEntityID = @IntVariable;
```

(from the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) on `sp_executesql`)

But I don't think this will fit your use case.

Comment: Best use QUOTENAME for the column name.

Comment: what is the key difference between your example and my example ? because i tried it this way with same error.

Comment: @Muflix apologies, looks like you can't concatenate the strings directly within the call to `sp_executesql` - I have edited my answer to reflect this and tested the result this time.

Comment: @TT. how exactly do you mean? When setting the `@column` value? Like `DECLARE @column NVARCHAR(MAX) = QUOTENAME('Id') + ' INT'`?

Comment: @3N1Gm4 thank you for your answer, it works now but in this approach is there any benefit against `exec()` function when it omits variable parameter ? I think it may allow sql injection because it does not know what has to be in @SQLString variable.

Comment: Have a quick Google: [EXEC vs. sp_executeSQL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/), [Stored procedure EXEC vs sp_executesql difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722201/stored-procedure-exec-vs-sp-executesql-difference) and [EXEC and sp_executesql – how are they different?](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/exec-and-sp_executesql-how-are-they-different/) were the first 3 results I got and all look useful.

Comment: `SET @sql = 'CREATE TYPE dbo.MyDataType AS TABLE ( ' + QUOTENAME(@column) + ')'`. Cf [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms176114.aspx) docu, if you can have arbitrary column names as a parameter eg names with spaces in it, or rectangular brackets, or special symbols, you need to use that function to properly escape the name.

Comment: @TT. but `SELECT QUOTENAME(@column)` returns `[Id INT]` - is it valid to wrap the column name **and** type in square brackets? I thought this was just for column names alone, which might contain spaces or other similar characters which cannot be used in an identified without wrapping it in the square brackets?

Comment: @3N1GM4 yes, but the main advantage is the security check for parameters which we are leaving, therefore i need to still check sql injection characters, therefore it looks same as the exec() function in terms of security

Comment: @Muflix if you have a further question on the specific benefits of one approach versus the other, or how they each work, I would suggest you post it as a separate question, or review the questions which already exist on SO dealing with that subject.

Comment: @3N1GM4 Oh right. Not a good idea of the OP to pass column name and type in one parameter. The quotename is just for the name, not the type.

Comment: @TT. ok, that's what I thought - agree it's not good to pass both together, just wanted to make my example as analogous to OP's question as possible.