# Select the store procedure parameter as aliases in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select the store procedure parameter as aliases in select statement in `sql`

example i have two parameter in store procedure

```
@programcode int,
@class int
```

Query where I want use those parameters as alias.

```
select programcode as @programcode from tbl_name
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This looks like an "X/Y problem" to me.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: i have multiple parameter in select statement but in those one parameter i want to select like above

Comment: @LovedeepSingh check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want a column alias to be a number?

In any case, you can write this as:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);

SET @sql = N'
SELECT programcode  AS [' + CAST(@programcode AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ']
FROM tbl_name
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Numbers are not really recommended for column aliases, so they need to use escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
DECLARE @SqlText nvarchar(MAX);
SET @sqlText = N'SELECT programcode  AS ' + CAST(@programcode AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' FROM tbl_name'
Exec (@sqlText)
```

Comment: This will cause an error: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SELECT programcode  AS ' to data type int". You must first cast the int to a nvarchar. For ints, use `nvarchar(11)` to make sure you have enough chars to convert even if the value is the minimum value of int (-2,147,483,648).

Comment: Also, If `@programcode` wasn't an int, this kind of query would be a security risk since it would be an open door for sql injection attacks.

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks @ZoharPeled

Comment: Good, but why `varchar(max)`? the maximum number of chars you might need is 11, as I've already written in the first comment. Using `max` for everything is a bad habit that can drastically effect performance.

Comment: What Zohar said. Using nvarchar(max) is just lazy. Using varchar(max) is also lazy and inconsistent.

Comment: after apply the above query i am getting below error "Must declare the scalar variable "@programcode""    @programcode is store procedure parameter and its delared already

Comment: `EXEC` should be avoided and `sp_executesql` should be used instead:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722201/stored-procedure-exec-vs-sp-executesql-difference