# in operator issue in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
dECLARE @LS_SQL CHAR(100)
dECLARE @SQL varCHAR(max)
SET @LS_SQL=ltrim('''STOCK IN HAND'',''STORE'',''PRODUCT''')

set @SQL='SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE GROUPNAME IN(' + rtrim(@LS_SQL) + ')'
PRINT @SQL
execute @SQL
```

result

> SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE GROUPNAME IN('STOCK IN
>   HAND','STORE','PRODUCT') Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 9 Could
>   not find stored procedure 'SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE GROUPNAME
>   IN('STOCK IN HAND','STORE','PRODUCT')'.

Comment: did you ever read the error message yourself? It clearly says that STORED PROCEDURE IS NOT FOUND. you are running direct query on EXECUTE Method which expect a store procedure name.

Answer (score 2):

This command

```
execute @SQL
```

run a procedure. If you wan to run dynamic sql you should use below command:

```
exec (@SQL)
```

you can also use

```
execute sp_sqlexec @SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx), like:

```
exec sp_executesql @stmt = @SQL
```

you can see more help here [Dynamic SQL - EXEC(@SQL) versus EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548090/dynamic-sql-execsql-versus-exec-sp-executesqlsql)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dECLARE @LS_SQL CHAR(100)
dECLARE @SQL varCHAR(max)
SET @LS_SQL=ltrim('''STOCK IN HAND'',''STORE'',''PRODUCT''')

set @SQL='SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE GROUPNAME IN(' + rtrim(@LS_SQL) + ')'
PRINT @SQL
execute sp_sqlexec @SQL
```