# Is there some simple way to generate script to drop all foreign constraints in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to create a db reset script.

1: Drop all FK constraints

2: Truncate all tables (I can manage this, but help appreciated)

3: Recreate all FK constraints.

How can I generate step 1 and 3 from the current state of the db?

Comment: Why not disable them? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737115/turn-off-constraints-temporarily-ms-sql

Comment: There is a way. Look at all sys views, they have the information you need. But are you asking us to write that for you?

Comment: pritaeas: Thx good idea.
Szymon: You  are right. The question is actually misleading. I know that this metainfo accessible via system tables or schema views, I am just do not want to actually reinvent them if anybody have some utility for it, although I do not want to write it for me by others from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to [look up all foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server-2005) for the table in questions (or a [list of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql) from the DB first), then [disable all foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737115/turn-off-constraints-temporarily-ms-sql) -by their name-, do the truncate and re-enable keys. You might need [dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548090/dynamic-sql-execsql-versus-exec-sp-executesqlsql) throughout this process.
Technically, you can put this fairly simple script/SP together in minutes after 2-3 mins googling for the solution.
If it's about mass-destroying all data, I'd also consider dropping the DB (or tables in question) and re-creating from a .sql, as that probably is faster.

Comment: Dropping the DB would be not as efficient as there are a lot of Views and SPs etc in it