# Use sql variable as where clause in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

i want to do this:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(max) 
DECLARE @cnt bigint    
set @str= 'where column=value'
set @cnt= (select count(*) from user+@str)
```

but the where clause is not working. getting no error but it will just ignore the where condition.

Comment: Take a look at this question as to some of the pitfalls highlighted in the answers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548090/dynamic-sql-execsql-versus-exec-sp-executesqlsql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I previously suggested wrapping your last line in `EXEC()`, but you can't do this and return results to a variable.  To do that, use the following in place of your last line:

```
create table #temp (theCount int)
insert into #temp EXEC('select count(*) from Photos '+@str)
set @cnt= (select top 1 theCount from #temp)
drop table #temp
```

Comment: getting this error:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
for your line

Answer (score 1):

Check below code, in your case condition is dynamic so you need to dynamic  sql.

```
DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @str nvarchar(500);
set @str= 'where column=value'  
SELECT @sSQL = N'SELECT @retvalOUT = COUNT(*) FROM user '+ @str +' '  ;  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT';
EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, @ParmDefinition, @retvalOUT=@retval OUTPUT;
SELECT @retval;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the execute sql syntax http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Hope this will solve your problem