# How can I use a variable within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am just wondering if it is possible to use a variable within a stored procedure. For Example:

```
    CASE    @productType
    WHEN 1 THEN
    DECLARE @table = ‘products1’
    WHEN 2 THEN
    DECLARE @table = ‘products2’
END

SELECT * FROM @table;
```

Obviously this does not work, just wondering if there is a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can use dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @productType INT = 1
DECLARE @table  NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql    NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @table = 
    CASE @productType
        WHEN 1 THEN 'products1'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'products2'
    END

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table);

EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a if else if statement :

```
DECLARE @productType INT = 2
IF @productType = 1
    SELECT * FROM products1
ELSE IF @productType = 2
    SELECT * FROM products2
```

Or Using `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @productType INT = 1;
DECLARE @table  NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql    NVARCHAR(MAX);


SELECT @table = 
    CASE @productType
        WHEN 1 THEN 'products1'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'products2'
    END;

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Yes, This was a simple example but I am wanting to use this on much more complex procedures where using this method would be unwieldily

Comment: Can you provide an explantion of your scenario, much of the time it's better to avoid dynamic SQL

Comment: I see, Is this for performance reasons? the scenario is basically because I have a very long statement where the table name must be changed throughout. there are many scenarios so i would have to have 20+ if statements and copy paste a lot of code

Comment: No this is for security reasons, in your case you should use EXEC sp_executesql @sql rather than EXEC (@sql). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548090/dynamic-sql-execsql-versus-exec-sp-executesqlsql