# How to do dynamic insert with SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

**Problem:** I have two tables and I want to retrieve one value from `Estatus` table like:

```
var @status = SELECT ID FROM [adm].[Estatus] WHERE Nombre = 'ACTIVA'
```

and then insert it into another table like:

```
INSERT INTO [adm].[Users] 
VALUES ('pepe@gmail.com', + @status + 'new')
```

but I get error into `var @status`

> Incorrect syntax near '@status'

I try to use `DECLARE` instead var but it doesn't work too

What do I need to get value and the use it in my insert query? Regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548090/dynamic-sql-execsql-versus-exec-sp-executesqlsql

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server and column ID is of type int:

```
DECLARE @status INT

SELECT  TOP 1
        @status = ID
FROM    adm.Estatus
WHERE   Nombre = 'ACTIVA'

INSERT  INTO adm.[Users]
VALUES  ( 'pepe@gmail.com', CONCAT(@status, 'new') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO adm.[Users] (EmailColumn, StatusColumn)
SELECT 'pepe@gmail.com', CONVERT(VARCHAR, Id) + 'new'
FROM adm.[EStatus]
WHERE Nombre = 'ACTIVA'
```