# Generate multiple UPDATE statements and execute them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to generate multi-update statement.

This code:

```
DECLARE @query as varchar(max);
SET @query =

'declare @data_dzis as nvarchar(10)
declare @data_wczoraj as nvarchar(10)
SELECT @data_dzis=convert(varchar,convert(int,convert(datetime,convert(date,GETDATE()))))
SELECT @data_wczoraj=convert(varchar,convert(int,convert(datetime,convert(date,GETDATE()-1))))

    Select
        ''update V_''+IdStr + '' set start='' + @data_wczoraj + '' where DataVersionId=0 and start='' + @data_dzis +'';''
    FROM [KW_GRECOS].[dbo].[Variable]
    where Granularity=0 and IdStr<>''_ROOT_FOLDER_'''

exec(@query);
```

...generates list of updates as a recordset:

```
update V_G012 set start=43085 where DataVersionId=0 and start=43086;
update V_G059 set start=43085 where DataVersionId=0 and start=43086;
update V_G002a set start=43085 where DataVersionId=0 and start=43086;
update V_G0122 set start=43085 where DataVersionId=0 and start=43086;
update V_103D set start=43085 where DataVersionId=0 and start=43086;
update V_G072 set start=43085 where DataVersionId=0 and start=43086;
update V_G201 set start=43085 where DataVersionId=0 and start=43086;
update V_G001a set start=43085 where DataVersionId=0 and start=43086;
update V_G067a set start=43085 where DataVersionId=0 and start=43086;
```

I don't know how to execute them automatically.
I had to copy them and manually and execute, but that's not my point.

Comment: Because it boils down to needing a tutorial on dynamic SQL, this might as well be a duplicate of [Dynamic SQL - EXEC(@SQL) versus EXEC SP\_EXECUTESQL(@SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548090/dynamic-sql-execsql-versus-exec-sp-executesqlsql)

Comment: What error are you getting?  If no error what problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Your update statements make it seem like you have different tables describing the same data entities. That is a bad database design and should be refactored if possible.
All these `V_ + IdStr` tables should be a single table, where the `IdStr` is just another column inside.

Assuming this can't be done, I believe the rest of my answer is what you are looking for:

Change your `@query` variable to `nvarchar(max)` instead of `varchar(max)` and use `sp_executeSql` to get the update statements as an output variable.
Add a variable to concatenate the query results into (I've called it `@statements` in my example, note the lines with the `Added this!` comment):

```
DECLARE @query as nvarchar(max),
        @Update nvarchar(max);

SET @query =

'declare @data_dzis as nvarchar(10)
declare @data_wczoraj as nvarchar(10)
SELECT @data_dzis=convert(varchar,convert(int,convert(datetime,convert(date,GETDATE()))))
SELECT @data_wczoraj=convert(varchar,convert(int,convert(datetime,convert(date,GETDATE()-1))))
Set @statemets = '''';  -- Added this!
Select @statemets += -- Added this!
        ''update V_''+IdStr + '' set start='' + @data_wczoraj + '' where DataVersionId=0 and start='' + @data_dzis +'';''
    FROM [KW_GRECOS].[dbo].[Variable]
    where Granularity=0 and IdStr<>''_ROOT_FOLDER_'''

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@statemets nvarchar(max) OUTPUT', @statemets=@Update OUTPUT

PRINT @Update
--EXECUTE sp_executesql  @Update
```

Once you see that the `@Update` variable contains the correct update statements, remove the `Print` row and uncomment the `Execute` row.

[See a simplified live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/PQYTU13088)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all that in the @query
Not tested

```
declare @data_dzis    as nvarchar(10)
declare @data_wczoraj as nvarchar(10)
SELECT @data_dzis    = convert(varchar,convert(int,convert(datetime,convert(date,GETDATE()))))
SELECT @data_wczoraj = convert(varchar,convert(int,convert(datetime,convert(date,GETDATE()-1))))

DECLARE @query as nvarchar(max);
SET @query = 'Select ''update V_''+ IdStr + '' set start='' + @data_wczoraj + 
             '' where DataVersionId=0 and start='' + @data_dzis +'';''
             FROM [KW_GRECOS].[dbo].[Variable]
             where Granularity=0 and IdStr<>''_ROOT_FOLDER_'''

exec(@query);
```

Comment: While your observation is correct, it doesn't answer the question. Also, you forgot a `'` before the `Select`.