# select with parameter instead of field name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I use a parameter instead of a field name like:

```
Declare @Thecode varchar(10)
Set @Thecode= ‘code’   --'code' is field name. 
Select @Thecode from sqltable
```

Comment: A table has _columns_, not fields.

Comment: In sql is not allowed  the use of vars for object name ..

Comment: With [DYNAMIC SQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correction in your query:

```
SET @Thecode= ‘code’   --'code' is field name. 
SET @query='Select '+@Thecode+' from sqltable'
EXECUTE(@query)
```

There are two ways to execute dynamic SQL in SQL Server: use the `sp_executesql` system stored procedure or the `EXECUTE()` operator.
And for more details about the dynamic SQL execution Follow the below link:

> https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: A bit of explanation around the concept of *dynamic sql* would make this a better answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Dynamic SQL.

If it is so then please check the following solution:

**Note**: Tested in SQL Server 2008 R2

```
Declare @Thecode varchar(10)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)

Set @Thecode= 'code'   --'code' is field name. 

SET @query = 'SELECT '+ @Thecode +' from sqltable';

EXEC(@query)
```

Always mention the DBMS in the tags while posting the question. And take care of [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548090/dynamic-sql-execsql-versus-exec-sp-executesqlsql)

For more details about [Dynamic SQL](http://www.benkotips.com/pages/DynamicSQL.aspx).

Comment: This one will actually work (as an example) because you correctly use single quotes.